# Playing a shuffled and looped soundtrack in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Trying to use Audio() to choose a random track from a list, play it to the end, and then choose another. (At the moment I don't mind if it chooses the same track again).

The script I wrote sort of works in Explorer (but it seems to prevent all my other scripts on the page from running), and doesn't seem to do anything in Chrome or Edge. I am very new at this, if possible please explain like I'm four and a half.

I hoped the page would start playing a track after the user interaction, and then keep playing tracks. I do get audio in Explorer but no other browsers (and in Explorer it seems to prevent other scripts from running).

```
<script>
// ------------------------------------
// Play audio tracks randomly hopefully
// ------------------------------------

    // User interacts with web page
    window.alert("The Voyage of The Ink");

    // Define an array of music tracks
    const tracks = [ "thunder_step.mp3", "witches_dance.mp3", "old_ship_2.mp3", "triste_coeur.mp3", "grumbledrums.mp3"];

    // Create a new Audio element
    var audioElement = new Audio();

    // Define a function to play the next track
    function playNextTrack() {

        // Generate a random number between 0 and the number of tracks in the array
        var randomNumber = ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))+1);

        // Use the random number to select a track from the array
        const track = tracks[randomNumber];

        // Set the src property of the Audio element to the selected track
        audioElement.src = track;

        // Play the track
        audioElement.play();
        }

    // Set the onended event of the Audio element to call the playNextTrack function
    audioElement.onended = playNextTrack;

    // Start playing the first track
    playNextTrack();
</script>
```

In context: https://github.com/franciscrot/Strange-Cities/blob/main/music.js

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to play the audio on the page load. Modern browsers won't let you do this.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

> Note: A common gotcha is trying to play an audio element immediately
> on page load. Modern browser's default autoplay policy will block that
> from happening. Refer to Firefox and chrome for best practices and
> work around.

Use an event listener to start the audio.